# Accumulation Points of the Set $(0,1)$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I understand that $0$ and $1$ are accumulation points on this set, but isn't $0.5$ an accumulation point also? Or anything in the interval for that matter. Any neighborhood of $0.5$ would contain infinitely many points in the set $(0,1)$, so it should be an accumulation point right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are indeed correct. Every value $x \in (0,1)$ is an accumulation point, as is $0,1$, as you guessed. Therefore, the closure of $(0,1)$ in $\mathbb{R}$, using the standard topology, is $[0,1]$.

Comment: So the same goes for $[0,1]$? The inclusion or exclusion of the endpoints doesn't make a difference right? Since the set is still bounded.

Comment: @help Indeed! Remember, a point is an accumulation point if every open neighborhood contains a point in the set other than itself. Every value in $[0,1]$ has a an open neighborhood $(a,b)$ that 'hits' the set at some value other than itself, hence is an accumulation point. Thus in this case, the closure of $[0,1]$ is $[0,1]$, after all, it's a closed set!

Comment: Makes complete sense, my textbook didn't seem to answer that question and neither did the internet. Thanks!

Comment: @help Just note this is not true for all sets. For example, no point of $S=\{1/n \colon n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ is an accumulation point in $\mathbb{R}$ - a sufficiently small interval around any of the values will 'miss' all of the others. The value $0$ is an accumulation point of $S$, but it is not in $S$.